# How do I get good equipment?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any strategies for getting better weapons/items in Realm of the Mad God?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63265/are-there-any-strategies-for-getting-better-weapons-items-in-realm-of-the-mad-go)

I've been playing RotMG for a while now and just recently I was given a T10 robe and T10 staff and I had been having a hard time getting good equipment so when I got a necromancer to lvl 20, I thought I'd go to the centre of the realm and try to fight some of the harder bosses and find some blue bags but still I was no match for the monsters there even with T10 equipment.

How do I get good equipment?

Answer (score 2):

You need to play very safe. Only shoot at the edges of the screen where you think they are, and if you're taking damage, heal yourself, or hit your hotkey to teleport back to the Nexus. Eventually, you'll either get some better gear to fight harder monsters, or get potions to trade for better gear in the Nexus. It's a really long grinding process, and you'll need quick fingers. Hope this helps.